# VS2013 intellisense in javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

So, I found out that variables declared after the return statement in a function do not show up in VS2013 intellisense.

An example:

```
function getService(){
  var service = {
    getNames: getNames
  };
  return service; //<--intellisense not working on variables declared 
                  //   below this line

  function getNames(){
    var test = {
       first: '',
       second: ''
    };
    test. //<-- here intellisense does not show 
          //    either the test variable or the first or
          //    second properites of the object.
  }
}
```

Any know a way to remedy this?
Or do I simply have to rearrange the code and put the return statement in the end?

Comment: Well, code after `return` statement does not make much sense. So yes, rearranging seems like the way to go here

Comment: @GôTô In this case, the code after return does make sense; `getNames` is still available in `getService`. So I would probably submit a bug report and put the return at the end of the function.

Comment: @jgillich What it the point in putting this function after the `return` statement? What is the benefit?

Comment: Your example works fine for me

Comment: For me intellisense has always been a bit wonky.  But remember, you can always manually trigger it with ctrl-space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works fine for me.

Try making sure you have intellisense enabled and there is no conflicting plugins.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. I still can't get it to work. Intellisense is enabled and I don't have any related/conflicting plugins. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: @Molotch nope sorry. Id suggest you close this question and file a bug report with Microsoft.